# Is it possible to simplify this scala match statement using @ syntax?

Tags: scala

Is it possible to simplify the following `match` statement using `@` syntax?

```
foo match {
  case f: Foo => y(f)
  case f if forceY => y(f)
  case _ => x
}
```

where `forceY` is a `boolean`.

I've tried the following but getting compile errors and it does look like possibly questionable syntax for the compiler to interpret. Perhaps this is impossible to express?

```
foo match {
  case f @(_: Foo | _ if forceY) => y(f)
  case _ => x
}
```

Comment: `@` is useful for matching something _inside_ a nested construct: `case x @Some(Some(x)) => use x`. What you want is grouping several predicates, not binding a value from inside the predicate.

Comment: thanks - i don't think it's only used for nested situations actually, i believe i've seen it in error handling where you want the `e` to capture different types of exceptions which you want to handle identically and that was done using the `|` syntax. but i do agree i've never seen it with an `if` situation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
foo match {
  case f if f.isInstanceOf[Foo] || forceY => y(f)
  case _ => x
}
```

You cannot use `@` specifically because the syntax `f: Foo` can only appear in the matching part of `case`, not in the condition (after `if`).

The original version isn't too bad, either. If what you actually have in the right hand side is longer than just `y`, you can define the `y` explicitly and leave the three cases as they are, as they read just fine.

Comment: thanks very much, i wanted to avoid using `isInstanceOf` but that isn't part of my question so this seems like the only way to accomplish it?

Comment: What is the problem with `isInstanceOf`? If `y` secretly has two overrides, that wasn't clear from the question.

Comment: there is no issue in this specific example since the force-boolean implies that `y` can handle `_` - i just in general dislike it because it creates a coupling if you then need to refer the the variable as `Foo`. In this case, that would be an unnecessarily purist approach though. But I'm curious if you can think of a way to do it without the `isInstanceOf`? because I could easily construct  an example where the `isInstanceOf` would be significant and I'll need to cast. Hope this made sense.

Comment: If you need to cast in one case, then the right hand can't be the same as the other case where you don't know anything else about `foo`, so don't merge them.

Comment: imagine a case where i have super type `Foo` and three subtypes `FooA`, `FooB`, `FooC`. I want to handle either FooA OR FooB if the boolean is true. (and the `y` can handle any `Foo`). I guess in that case you are saying the only option is to keep two separate `case`s?

Comment: No, that can still be handled with `isInstanceOf`.

Comment: ah right i STILL don't need to cast because my `y` must, definitionally, be able to handle both if i'm trying to reuse it, doh.  ok, so you are right, i cannot construct an example where i'll have a coupling with `isInstaceOf` and `asInstanceOf`. I'm just conditioned to avoid `isInstanceOf` in scala but that's for the coupling reason.... ok i'm satisfied your answer is the best one, thanks very much for the back-and-forth :)

Comment: You can also leave the original version as is if you want :)